# Session cookie getting dropped during redirect

Tags: php, http, cookies, session-cookies

So I have this really weird problem.  I have been rattling my head over this, and I'm thinking I'm missing something obvious.  I have a web application with a custom session handler that encrypts the session data when stored on the server end.  It works perfectly until it encounters a new piece of code I just added.

```
if( $behaviorDefined === false ) {
    if( !isset( $_GET['systempage'] ) || $_GET['systempage'] != "wikiconfig" ) {
        header( "HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect", true, 307 );
        header( "Location: index.php?page=systemconfig&systempage=wikiconfig", true, 307 );
        echo "This site is not set up yet.";
        exit( 1 );
    }
}
```

It's even weirder, when I comment out the 2 header calls, and load just the the text being echoed, the cookie is only set every other page load, when I click refresh.

Some information:

- $behaviorDefined is a boolean that is true when the declaring function has determined the site is setup correctly.  On false, it's supposed to redirect to the page that let's the user set up the site configuration values.
- Those GET values are where the site is supposed to be if it needs to redirect, so to avoid infinite redirects.
- You can assume the session handler works as intended, as the issue only happens when the code execution enters this part of the code, and this session handler has been in use in production for around a year without issue.
- The cookie being set is HttpOnly and the path is set to the root containing the index.php file.  The path matches the URI path.
- Every time a HEAD request is made to the web page, via curl on the CLI, Set-Cookie is defined with the cookie needing to be set.

Any ideas what could cause the browser to drop the cookie?  I'm totally clueless on this.  Any way to check the outgoing headers from within PHP?

Comment: Try passing absolute url in location header with protocol `header( "Location: http://yordomain.com/welcome.php?page=systemconfig&systempage=wikiconfig", true, 307 );`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve it, and all the other redirects work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it decided to start breaking now, but set cookie was being called before session start.  Normally session start would change the set cookie from "Set-Cookie: sessionName=deleted" to "Set-Cookie: sessionName={sessionid}", for some reason it was only doing that when it wasn't receiving a cookie, and then didn't bother to pass the cookie back when it did receive one.  I've moved it to be called after session_start() which seems to create consistent results, but I remember being told that set cookie should always be called first.  Maybe I had that wrong the entire time?

Comment: Yea no session function will work untill you call session_start()

Comment: including setcookie?  As I recall session_start defines the cookie to include the sessionID if a setcookie defined the cookie from before.

Comment: Do you use any of php's session functions in your custom session implementation?

Comment: Yes.  See https://github.com/cyberpower678/Cyberbot_II/blob/master/IABot/www/Includes/session.php